# PHP cURL not fetching webpage

Tags: php, curl

As you can see in the code, I am trying to execute an FQL query and retrieve results. The query I generate is completely fine because I have tested it through my browser. I first used file_get_contents() to retrieve the webpage but it was gicing me a 400 Bad Request Error. Somebody suggest cURL instead.

The code segment given below gives me **false** for $query. If I uncomment the urlencode() line, the script goes on and on and hits the maximum execution time limit. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $limit = $start + 100;
    $query = "select post_id, created_time, actor_id, message, attachment, comments, likes, type  from stream where source_id = $id limit $start, ". $limit;
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=$query&access_token=$token";
    //$url = urlencode($url);
    echo $url.'<br>';
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, "tcp://10.3.3.3:8080"); 
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Hi!');
    $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    var_dump($query);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
```

edit: Accessing another URL, file_get_contents gave me this error "failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy". Since this one is also HTTPS, cURL might also be facing the same problem. I thought this might lead to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you reuse your `$query` variable just before you dump it.

Second, use urlencode on your (first) `$query` variable. (Facebooks $token does not need url encoding)

---

**edit** (does not fit inside in a comment)

I've just tried this myself:

```
<?
    $token = $_GET["token"];
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $start = 0;
    $limit = $start + 100;
    $query = urlencode("select post_id, created_time, actor_id, message, attachment, comments, likes, type from stream where source_id = $id limit $start, ". $limit);
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=$query&access_token=$token";

    echo $url.'<br>';
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $curlres = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    var_dump($query);
    print "\n\n";
    var_dump($curlres);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
?>
```

This works without problems.
PM me if you want to try this, and I'll give you the URL. I'm not confortable with releasing this into the wild..
Pherhaps the source is your proxy ..

---

**edit**

Aw what the hell .. go nuts! ;)

http://hal.su/on/fbCurlTest.php?token=the%20token&id=the%id&start=0

replace the%20token with your token and replace the%20id with your id.

Comment: does reusing $query do any harm? Tried your second suggestion. didn't work

Comment: no, it does not. Try to keep this as simple as possible. Do you really need `curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Hi!');`?

Comment: Facebook's `$token` doesn't **currently** need URL encoding, but it can't hurt to do so in case they change its format in the future. I always err on the side of caution with Facebook's APIs.

Comment: @micha ofcourse I dont need that :P Removed it. Plus I used another variable instead of reusing. Still nothing

Comment: You're so generous @micha it worked perfectly. The problem I finally figured out is with HTTPS AND proxy as this page says: http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/371-How-to-use-file-get-contents-with-a-proxy and can I rely on this URL? I have to do things for my employer ;)

Comment: I'll keep the page live for a few more days, but you can't rely on it. Besides, how do you know you could trust me? Maybe I'm logging your accesstoken and id. There are more ways of circumventing a proxy. For example, the generated URL could be retrieved by javascript and a XMLHTTPRequest. Or you could buy a cheap shared hosting account with PHP and cURL support somewhere and run it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You should be `urlencode`ing `$query` and `$token`, not the whole URL.

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=" . urlencode($query) . "&access_token=" . urlencode($token);
```

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+post_id%2C+created_time%2C+actor_id%2C+message%2C+attachment%2C+comments%2C+likes%2C+type++from+stream+where+source_id+%3D+50245567013+limit+200%2C+300&access_token=[token hidden]   this is the url if I urlencode() $query and $token. Result is still boolean false

Comment: Are you certain your proxy is working? Why are you using one? It's also possible your custom user agent isn't being liked.

Comment: I am using the web behind a proxy. And yes I'm certain that it is working. I removed the user agent call completely